# If $A⊆P_1\cup P_2$, then $A⊆P_1$ or $A⊆P_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a commutative ring $R$, let $A$ be an ideal of $R$ and $P_1$, $P_2$ be prime ideals. If $A⊆P_1\cup P_2$, then $A⊆P_1$ or $A⊆P_2$.

I suppose $x_1\in A-P_1$ and $x_2\in A-P_2$ then $x_1\in P_2$, $x_2\in P_1$, and $x_1x_2\in P_1\cap P_2$. But I don't know what's the contradiction. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you've found your answers, and here's some supplementary info: This is a "toy" case of the [Prime avoidance lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance#Important_facts) (see the first bullet point).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Let $x=x_1+x_2$; if $x\in P_1$, then $x_1=x-x_2\in P_1$, so $x\notin P_1$; can you see a contradiction coming?

**Added:** Note that the suggested argument does not actually use the primality of $P_1$ and $P_2$. The generalization of this result to the union of more than two ideals does require that the ideals be prime, however.

Comment: Maybe you want to remark that your proof shows that the condition on $P_1,P_2$ to be prime is superfluous.

Comment: @YACP: Good point. I wonder if this was preparation for the general theorem, which does use primality.

Answer (score 3):

We may assume that $P_1\not \subset P_2$ and $P_2\not\subset P_1$. Pick $a\in P_2\setminus P_1$ and $b\in P_1\setminus P_2$, you can get a contradiction considering  $ax_1+bx_2$.