# If $I\subseteq P_1\cup P_2$ with $P_1, P_2$ prime ideals of $R$, then $I\subseteq P_1$ or $I\subseteq P_2$.

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

**Please note that I am not looking for a solution to the question in the title as it has been asked before.**

I was trying to prove this famous result to a friend:

> If $I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$ and $P_1, P_2$ are prime ideals of $R$ such that $I\subseteq P_1\cup P_2$, then $I\subseteq P_1$ or $I\subseteq P_2$.

The trouble is, I forgot the proof, and came up with a bizarre result that I would like feedback on.

**My proof attempt:**

> Suppose $I\subseteq P_1\cup P_2$. Suppose towards a contradiction that there exist $a\in I\cap (P_1\setminus P_2)$ and $b\in I\cap (P_2\setminus P_1)$. Then $a+b\in I$ since $I$ is an ideal. If $a+b\in P_1$, then $a+b-a=b\in P_1$, a contradiction. If $a+b\in P_2$, then $a+b-b=a\in P_2$, a contradiction. Thus it is not the case that there exist such $a, b$, and hence $I$ is completely contained in $P_1$ or $P_2$.

There are a few problems with this. Namely, I did not use the fact that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are prime, and I think this is quite obviously not true for ideals in general. But after investigating the proof, I don't quite see a problem with it.

Naturally, this brings us the question: *what is wrong with this proof?* Is the result actually true for two ideals in general? Why do we need primeness in any case?

Comment: This conclusion holds for any two ideals, not necessarily prime ideals, as in the first answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473245/if-a%e2%8a%86p-1-cup-p-2-then-a%e2%8a%86p-1-or-a%e2%8a%86p-2?rq=1.